# how to make an object move around a 2d grid array on its own towards other objects in java

Tags: java, arrays, object, multidimensional-array, move

OK so I have recently got my program to the point where it is allmost working, however I cant seem to figure out how to make my bug object move.

I have a class called AWorld that is populated with instances of a class method Randfood (ints between 0 and 9) in randomly placed possitions within the grid. It is also passed and instance of my class ABug as an attribute that is placed into the grip according to user input. my problem is I wish to make it move towards the food objects (my ints between 0-9) and when its next to them to have its energy level increased accordingly. it needs to only move towards an object when its within a set distance from it. i.e. 3 spaces in any direction, else just move randomly. my issue is i cant seem to figure out how to do that with my current code setup.

AWorld Class:

```
 package finalversion2;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;

public class AWorld {

    int x[] = new int[10], y[] = new int[10];
    int row = 25;
    int column = 25;
    char[][] map;

    public static int RandFood(int min, int max) {
        Random rand = new Random(); // Initializes the random function. 

        int RandNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min; //generates a random number within the max and min ranges 
        return RandNum; //returns the random number 
    }


    //Constructor
    //Sets up map array for the AWorld object
    //uses a bug that is passed to it
    public AWorld(ABug bug) {

        ABug bug1 = bug;

        map = new char[row][column];



        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {

            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < column; x1++) {

                map[i][x1] = ' ';

            }

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < column; i++) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int x = rand.nextInt(row);
            int y = rand.nextInt(column);
            map[x][y] = (char) RandFood(48, 57);
            map[bug1.getHPossistion()][bug1.getVPossistion()] = bug1.getSymbol(); // gets the bugs x and y possistion in the array (user defined) and puts it into the symbol variable 
        }



    }


    public void PrintWorld() {
        for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) //these next two for loops print the array to the screen 
        {
            System.out.print("|");
            for (int x1 = 0; x1 < column; x1++) {
                System.out.print(map[i][x1]);
            }
            System.out.println("|");
        }

    }
}

ABug:

    package finalversion2;

public class ABug 

{


    public static void main(){

    }

        private String species = new String(); //instance variables (defines data of object)
        private String name = new String();
        private String description = new String();
        private char symbol;
        private int hPossistion, vPossistion, energy, iD;

        public ABug(){

        }

        public ABug (String s, String n, String d, int h, int v, int e, int i){
            this.species = s;
            this.name = n;
            this.description = d;
            this.symbol = s.charAt(0);
            this.hPossistion = h;
            this.vPossistion = v;
            this.energy = e;
            this.iD = i;
        }




        //setters
        public void setSpecies(String s){
            this.species = s;
        }

        public void setName(String n){
            this.name = n;
        }

        public void setSymbol(char symbol){
            this.symbol = symbol;
        }

        public void setHPossistion(int x){
            this.hPossistion = x;
        }

        public void setVPossistion(int y){
            this.vPossistion = y;
        }

        public void setEnergy(int energy){
            this.energy = energy;
        }

        public void setID(int i){
            this.iD = i;
        }

        public void setDescription(String d){
            this.description = d;
        }

        //getters
        public String getSpecies(){
            return this.species;
        }

        public String getName(){
            return this.name;
        }

        public char getSymbol(){
            return this.symbol;
        }

        public int getHPossistion(){
            return this.hPossistion;
        }

        public int getVPossistion(){
            return this.vPossistion;
        }

        public int  getEnergy(){
            return this.energy;
        }

        public int getID(){
            return this.iD;
        }

        public String getDescription(){
            return this.description;
        }

        public String toString(){
            String BugData;
            BugData = name + " " + symbol + "\n" + species + "\n" + description;
            return BugData;
        }

}

enum Direction: 

    package finalversion2;


public enum Direction {
    NORTH,  EAST,   SOUTH,  WEST;
}
```

now im guessing I need to redraw my map each time i wish it to move using my enum based on a boolean response, i.e. call the printworld method but randomly move the bug. but wont that reprint my random ints?

please help. im very new to java.

Cheers in advance.

Comment: You only need to do this `Random rand = new Random();` and this `map[bug1.getHPossistion()][bug1.getVPossistion()] = bug1.getSymbol();` once, but it's in a loop. Now this looks like a school exercise, at least try to do it, because right now your main function is empty. You don't want us to write the program for you, right? :)